# Serial communication error with Arduino using a Threading.Timer

Tags: python, arduino, communication

In my python project, I use serial communication to send commands and receive responses from the Arduino. I have several tasks that need to occur cyclically, but in different time frames. For that, I use `threading.Timer`. Then, from time to time, I send a command to the Arduino, which returns a value (taken from the sensor).

Everything works perfectly. However, occasionally, when I press another button that sends information (considerably long) to the Arduino, the `Thread` simply stops being called when it should, as if the command was interrupted in the middle of the process, which causes an error in the serial communication of the thread.

No error information appears on the console.

Is there a way to force `threading.Timer` to wait for the last command to finish, so that it is executed?

Cyclical function:

```
def action_5_seconds(self):
    global state_banho
    if state_banho == False:
        self.apresenta_parametros()
    else:
        self.verify_pid_banho()
    self.verify_pid_lamp()

    #self.agente_ar_automatic()
    print("Threand 5s OK...")

    clock_5_sec = threading.Timer(5, self.action_5_seconds)
    clock_5_sec.start()
```

Function that sends to arduino:

```
def power_off_ar(self):
    serial_port.flush()
    serial_port.write(b's,2,99,3450,1650,450,450,450,1250,450,400,450,450,400,450,450,400,450,400,450,450,400,450,450,400,450,400,450,400,450,450,400,1300,450,400,450,450,400,450,450,400,450,400,450,400,450,450,400,450,450,400,450,1300,400,450,450,400,450,400,450,400,450,450,400,450,450,400,450,400,450,450,400,450,450,1250,450,400,450,1300,450,1250,450,450,400,450,450,400,450,400,450,1300,400,450,450,1250,450,1300,450,400,450,1250,450')
    #time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Comando Enviado para o AR")
```

Comment: From the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/threading.py#L1230), it looks like `Timer`s have a public `finished` attribute which is a `threading.Event`. Event objects have an internal flag that can be true or false — initially it is false. After the associated function is called, it is set to true, which implies you can check the status of a `Timer` instance by calling its `finished.is_set()` to determine whether the function has been run yet. This would be difficult to do the way your code is currently structured because `clock_5_sec` is a local variable.

Comment: Threading.Timer alone works well. The problem is when sending the serial command. For some reason, it stops working. I believe it is due to the time to send all values, because smaller commands (1 digit) continue sending without interrupting Threading.

Comment: Threads don't really execute concurrently in Python, for the most part they take turns running whenever one does I/O or sleeps. Anyway, I suggest you make `clock_5_sec` an instance attribute which will allow you to check the `Event` associated with the last `Timer` thread created (if any).